# Why is my powered up system allowing only 1 speed, & only with the remote button held down?

Tags: powered-up, remote-control

My new MOC has a powered up battery box & motor, but only will run at the fastest speed. There is no speed control, when there should be many speed options. Also, it will only operate at all, if the button on the remote is held down. The moment you release the forward or backward button, it stops. Is anyone able to help with figuring this out?

Comment: Hi Warren and welcome to Bricks.SE! You say this is your new MOC, but if it's your own creation then we can hardly offer support without knowing what you have built and which parts are you using to control it. Please post a photo of it, so that we can see what's the issue.

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing is bang-bang mode. If the hub isn't connected to a smart-device running the powered-up app and the connected motor isn't a train motor, it's how a powered up hub connected with a powered up remote behaves.

It's reasonably straight-forward to create a project in the powered-up app to implement gradual speed control, but I dislike this option because it requires you to have an additional device (smartphone or tablet) running along side your moc.

My go to solution for this is [Pybricks](https://pybricks.com/). It installs alternative firmware on your hub, allowing you to upload python programs to the hub.
For example here is [code](https://pybricks.com/projects/sets/technic/42160-audi-rs-q-e-tron/powered-up-remote/) to control the LEGO Technic Audi RS Q e-tron (42160) with the powered up remote.